# Which Sephardic siddurim lack the bracha "HaNoten LaYaef Koach?"

Tags: tefilla

Some Sephardic siddurim don't have the bracha "HaNoten LaYaef Koach (הנותן ליעף כח)" in them. Can anyone give me a list of siddurim that don't? The more comprehensive, the better.

Comment: Do you mean modern siddurim or historical siddurim?

Comment: Could you also explain why you are asking, one of the guidelines on this site that I think  would come in particularly handy here.

Comment: @RabbiKaii The bracha originated in ashkenazi lands and the shulchan aruch opposed saying it. Which sefardi siddurim jumped on the ashkenazi bandwagon (probably under influence of the arizal who used the ashkenazi text) is surely interesting data.

Comment: @DoubleAA Modern

Comment: FWIW I have used many sephardi sidurim and have not noticed any modern ones without the berakhah. It's included in Ish Matzliach, Yechave Daat, Sukat David, Avodat HaShem, Kavanat HaLev, and Sidur HaShelelm from Sala. Pretty sure it's also in the Sidur HaChidah, It's also in the Artscroll Sephardic siddur, which is based on a line of Livornese sidurim. The Artscroll often points out variant nusachot and doesn't say anything on hanoten l'yaef koach. Do you have an example of a modern one that doesn't have the berachah?

Comment: @Avraham my experience is similar to yours, but isn't the question you ask at the end of your comment the same question the OP is asking?

Comment: @יהושעק OP says "some Sephardic siddurim don't have the bracha." And in a follow up comment he says he is talking about modern sidurim. So it might be a helpful starting point if he can tell us which siddurim he is talking about that don't have it. If OP's question were "do any sephardic siddurim omit it based on the opinion of the Beit Yosef" I would agree with you.

Comment: Considering you're asking for a list of Sephardic siddurim that don't have the bracha, how do _you_ know that some of them don't have it? (The answer to this should be part of the question.)

Comment: @Avraham well put. That would indeed be a good strategy

Comment: The SnP siddur doesn't have it (https://archive.org/details/sederhatefilotvol1dailyandoccasionalprayersmosesgaster1901/page/n38/mode/2up).

Also, the Qoren Avotenu siddur notes that they said it without shem umalkhut in certain parts of Morocco (I want to say Meknes, but I'm not sure.)